# R: Extract column name for earliest and latest columns

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with multiple date columns in R.
I need to extract the column names of the earliest date in each row as below:

**Input Example Dataframe**

```
> df
Date1       Date2       Date3
2008-08-11  1995-02-25  2005-05-14
2010-06-18  2012-09-04  2003-01-16
2011-04-22  2006-11-05  1999-03-31
```

The line: `df$FirstDate <- apply(df[,c(1:3)], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)`
gives me the earliest dates in each row as desired but I also need to extract the name of the column (`df$FirstColumn`) as per desired output:

**Desired Output**

```
> df
Date1       Date2       Date3       FirstDate   FirstColumn
2008-08-11  1995-02-25  2005-05-14  1995-02-25  Date2
2010-06-18  2012-09-04  2003-01-16  2003-01-16  Date3
2011-04-22  2006-11-05  1999-03-31  1999-03-31  Date3
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in R?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**SAMPLE DATA**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date1 = c(1989,  1995,  2005),
  Date2 = c(2010,  2012,  2003),
  Date3 = c(2011,  2006,  1999)
)
```

The minima:

```
df$Min <- apply(df[, 1:3], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**SOLUTION**:

To collect the names of the columns in which the minima are located:

```
df$MinLocation <- apply(df[1:3], 1, function(x) names(x)[which.min(x)])
```

**RESULT**:

```
df
  Date1 Date2 Date3  Min MinLocation
1  1989  2010  2011 1989       Date1
2  1995  2012  2006 1995       Date1
3  2005  2003  1999 1999       Date3
```

Comment: thanks for that. It does work as long as the Dates are in **numeric** format to begin with

Comment: Is there a way to choose which column is picked in the event of a tie as @Nik suggested, but not using tidyverse package?

Comment: In the event of ties `apply(df[1:3], 1, function(x) names(x)[which.min(x)])` by default picks the *first* column in which the minmum value occurs. `which.min` does not seem to offer an additional argument to change that; but it's at least not random.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(
    FirstDate = pmin(Date1, Date2, Date3),
    FirstColumn = names(.)[max.col(as.matrix(.) == as.character(FirstDate))]
  )
```

In case two or more columns are in a tie for having the earliest date, the `ties.method` argument of `max.col()` determines which column is picked. See `?max.col`. The default is `random`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I can't use the tidyverse R package. Is there an alternative method that works?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to get the maximum names for a data frame with numeric columns is the following:

```r
max_col_name <- function(df, names, ties.method = c("random")) {
  names[max.col(df[, names], ties.method = ties.method)]
}
```

To make this `max.col`-appraoch work with dates, one needs to convert the dates to integers first. To further calculate the minimum instead of the maximum, one needs to add a negative sign in front of the integer matrix. This gives:

```r
min_date_name <- function(df, names, ties.method = c("random")) {
  df <- -vapply(df[names], as.integer, seq_len(nrow(df)))
  names[max.col(df[, names], ties.method = ties.method)]
}
```

Let's see if it works:

```r
df <- data.frame(Date1 = as.POSIXct(c("2008-08-11", "2010-06-18", "2011-04-22")),
                 Date2 = as.POSIXct(c("1995-02-25", "2012-09-04", "2006-11-05")),
                 Date3 = as.POSIXct(c("2005-05-14", "2003-01-16", "1999-03-31")))

df$MinDate <- min_date_name(df, c("Date1", "Date2", "Date3"))

df
#>        Date1      Date2      Date3 MinDate
#> 1 2008-08-11 1995-02-25 2005-05-14   Date2
#> 2 2010-06-18 2012-09-04 2003-01-16   Date3
#> 3 2011-04-22 2006-11-05 1999-03-31   Date3
```